# Why does a string stored in an integer gets printed out?

Tags: c, string, integer

```
int k= "hello";
printf("%s", k);
```

Why does this hello print out even though the data type of k is an integer?

Comment: Actually this gives a warning `initialization makes a integer out of pointer..` how did this code compiled for you??

Comment: @ThunderWiring The code will compile without errors (assuming no `-Werror` flag), only with warnings.

Comment: I don't know how. It compiled on CodeBlocks and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: right, im using -Werror

Comment: The code most likely will *not* run on a 64bit platform, as the upper 32bits of `"hello"`'s address are lost when this address gets stored in `k`, because `k` is only 32bits wide.

Comment: "*a string stored in an integer*" the integer only stores the address of the "string", not the "string" itself.

Answer (score 4):

Your code invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
int k= "hello";
```

You are trying to initialize an `int` with a string literal(a `char*`). This makes no sense and invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
printf("%s", k);
```

You are trying to print an `int` using `%s`, which expects a `char*`. This too makes no sense and invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but why does it work then?

Comment: What works? UB means anything could be the result. Stop doing stupid things like that. You'll mostly  get unexpected results.

Comment: that's why you should use `-Werror` flag when compiling~

Comment: One legal response to undefined behavior is to do what the programmer intended. However, you can't count on it. The above code won't work on an ILP32 model, or on a CPU like the 68k which has separate address and integer registers.

Answer (score 1):

> Note- What is been done is wrong and pretty much provides un-desirable
>   results ( ignoring warnings is a crime in some cases this is one of
>   those case ).

With reference to why it prints the string for you, here is my interpretation

In case of a given format specifier %s given argument is identified/interpreted as base address of a string ( char * ). now a char * and int are logically equal ( ignoring the signs and other properties that C exerts )

so at a very raw level

```
int a = "String" ;
```

probably looks like this

```
     a  contains Base address of String ( this is some read only location )
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  0x123456             |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+

    And String may be defines as below with 'S' at location 0x123456

0x123456  
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  S  | t   |  r  |  i  |  n  |  g  |  \0 |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

> Argument to %s format specifier will be treated as (char*)

Now in case of %s as format specifier program is supposed to scan each and every byte of memory starting at the given address and typecast to char and then then   print ( of course depending printable value or not results can be pretty to 
gruesome )

In our case though de-referencing the given value of a to char * does not create any problem hence no error, however this my not necessarily the case all time. with varying reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `hello` is a string literal and hence it is stored in the text section(along the code) of the executable, when you assign it to an integer, actually the pointer to the literal will be assigned to the integer. Since both are of same size usually(4 bytes), there wont be any problems like stack overflow.

The printf will work fine as it will go to the address stored in the variable(here k) and will print the string until an end of string `\0` is found.

Comment: "*Since both are of same size*" this typically will *not* be the case for a 64bit implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code disregards C's type system, so you need to disregard the type system when trying to understand your code.

I expect sizeof(int)==sizeof(char*) on your machine. The const char* literal is assigned to k. This works because each byte on your machine has an integer address. "Under the hood" of the type system, a pointer is just this integer.

The printf works because it interprets k as a const char* to a null-terminated array, which is what you assigned to k.

As others have pointed out, your code isn't guaranteed to work, so it shouldn't be in any software you plan to release.